# Create generator to read each line in text file in reverse order

Tags: python, split, generator

I am trying to read each lines in a text file in reverse direction.  And I am trying to do it through generator. I have written `parser_entries()` which takes an iterable thing and return lines and yields takes an iterable thing that returns lines and yields parsed entries one at a time (this must be a generator).

`sample.txt`:

```
2018/03/25-00:08:48.638553  508     7FF4A8F3D704     snononsonfvnosnovoosr
2018/03/25-10:08:48.985053 346K     7FE9D2D51706     ahelooa afoaona woom
2018/03/25-20:08:50.486601 1.5M     7FE9D3D41706     qojfcmqcacaeia
2018/03/25-24:08:50.980519  16K     7FE9BD1AF707     user: number is 93823004
2018/03/26-00:08:50.981908 1389     7FE9BDC2B707     user 7fb31ecfa700
2018/03/26-10:08:51.066967    0     7FE9BDC91700     Exit Status = 0x0
2018/03/26-15:08:51.066968    1     7FE9BDC91700     std:ZMD:
```

Solution:

```
def parser_entries(lines=iter(reversed(list(file)))):
    line = lines.split('.', maxsplit=1)
    yield (line[0], line[1])

with open('a.txt') as f:
    lines = parser_entries(f)
    date_part, line = next(lines)
```

And I am getting below error while trying my solution:

```
line = lines.split('.', maxsplit=1)
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: You say that you want to iterate in the reverse direction however your desired result is the first line??

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the `.638553` to be in the `data_part`? It's the fractions of the second, I believe.

Comment: Sure but the error is the placement of the generator as a default argument value. Here I was thinking of how to read a file by lines backwards.

Comment: @Primusa, sorry, it was b mistake. Updated!

Comment: @martineau, Yes, I am sure I don't want the `.638553` to be in date_part.

Comment: @DanD., I am dealing with generators first time. So, I am not sure how it works.

Comment: Do you really only want the last line?

Comment: @DanD., Then I want to iterate over them using next(). I want whenver next(lines) called it should get me the value for date_Part and line.

Comment: @DanD., I have updated question, I think now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sequence slicing to do this as illustrated below:

```
def my_generator(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        for line in reversed(tuple(file)):
            index = line.find('.')  # Find first occurrence of '.' character.
            if index > -1:  # Character found?
                yield line[:index], line[index:-1]
            else:
                pass  # Not sure what you want to happen...

for data_part, line in my_generator('a_sample.txt'):
    print('data_part: {!r}, line: {!r}'.format(data_part, line))
```

Output:

```
data_part: '2018/03/26-15:08:51', line: '.066968    1     7FE9BDC91700     std:ZMD:'
data_part: '2018/03/26-10:08:51', line: '.066967    0     7FE9BDC91700     Exit Status = 0x0'
data_part: '2018/03/26-00:08:50', line: '.981908 1389     7FE9BDC2B707     user 7fb31ecfa700'
data_part: '2018/03/25-24:08:50', line: '.980519  16K     7FE9BD1AF707     user: number is 93823004'
data_part: '2018/03/25-20:08:50', line: '.486601 1.5M     7FE9D3D41706     qojfcmqcacaeia'
data_part: '2018/03/25-10:08:48', line: '.985053 346K     7FE9D2D51706     ahelooa afoaona woom'
data_part: '2018/03/25-00:08:48', line: '.638553  508     7FF4A8F3D704     snononsonfvnosnovoosr'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I don't want to strict the split by a constant, it might get change because this is a sample from logs. Is there any way we can use spit()?

Comment: Yes, `split()` could be used, if you're sure the `.` doesn't appear anywhere else on the lines of the file. The are also other possibilities. Reversing the order of lines of the file is going to require reading them all into memory first, is that OK?

Comment: I am not sure, It might be used in other places too. Can't we pass maxsplit paramter in split()?

Comment: user15051990: Yes, using `maxsplit` would probably work, but I'm using slicing to do the splitting in my answer — see update.